# Stringed IF ELSE Functions exceeding the Excel character limit?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, character-limit

New excel user looking for a solution to a character limit issue with my ifelse() function. I am creating a database of people's home towns and their corresponding districts/counties/states. I have written a function that allows the district to come up automatically when the town is entered, by writing in the 'District' column:

IF([@Town] = "town1", "state1", "")  & IF([@Town] = "town2", "state2", "")

With [@Town] being the town column. However, as I have hundreds of towns and assosiated districts I have now reached the limit for charters.

How would I resolve this issue?
Is it a case of the wrong approach making this formula far too complicated than it needs to be?
Is there a work around?

Cheers,
Joe

Comment: create a lookup table and use vlookup.

Comment: thank you I'll try that

Comment: @ScottCraner please correct me if I am wrong, but by 'create a lookup table' do you mean manually type in the various towns and associated districts and then using a vlookup function in a third column? I am creating a database of towns/villages in Uganda and therefore in this instance the lookup table would be almost equally as long as the database I am trying to create. Therefore in this instance wouldn't doing this defeat the purpose of timesaving on my end? Thanks

Comment: You would create a table with two columns.  The first column will be the name of the Town.  The Second would be the name of the state in which that town is found.  Then Where you are putting the long `IF` with all the information you would simply use: `=VLOOKUP([@Town] , G:H,2,FALSE)` where `G:H` holds the 2 column table you created.

Answer (score 1):

Create a lookup table of all your towns and their respective state.

[image]

Then use VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP([@Town], G:H,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: ah I see what you mean now. Thank you for you're help!